# Ubuntu starts in tty1 only - no screens detected - cant' startx

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg, screen, xserver

I just rebooted my laptop and I can't start the gui. I logged in in text mode and `startx` says no screens detected.

I have tried to purge and install the `nvidia` driver,

- I have tried to reinstall and reconfigure `xserver-xorg`...
- I have tried to manually add my device (video card), monitor and screen in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` and....

I have no gui at all. I need my desktop environment back. Can anyone help?

Comment: (1) Add laptop/video card model (2) Post `/var/log/Xorg.log.0`

Comment: please, post full error log which appears after you hit `startx`. which desktop are you trying to start? what did you do prior the reboot?

Comment: Here is how i solved it. Installed nvidia-310.19 instead of nvidia-current
1. sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa 

2. sudo apt-get update 

3. cd && wget http://dl.dropbox.com/u/47950494/upubuntu.com/nvidia-310.19 

4. chmod +x nvidia-310.19

5. cd && sudo sh nvidia-310.19 

6. sudo reboot

Comment: @user1930341 1) Please don't just run software from unsupported sources. Nividia driver 310.19 is packaged for Ubuntu and also has an official Nvidia source. 2) Please don't put answers in comments. (This is a Q&A site and answers should be posted as answers)